# What is the fabric2 alternative for Fabric1 env.hosts and env.hosts_name

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, statsd, collectd

In my code I wish to have a list of hosts and send a different parameter to each host.

Currently I find the index in the array and use that to determine the input

```
index = env.hosts.index(env.host_name)
```

Hosts and host_name is no longer used in fabric 3 with it saying.

```
The primary API is now properly OOP: instantiate Connection objects and call their methods. These objects encapsulate all connection state (user, host, gateway, etc) and have their own SSH client instances.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Fabric 2, you connect to a host by instantiating a `Connection` object. You can access its host by invoking the `host` attribute:

```
conn = Connection('192.168.11.12')
print(conn.host)
```

Should you need to connect to multiple servers, you will need to instantiate a `SerialGroup` composed of multiple connections

```
g = SerialGroup('192.168.11.12', '192.168.11.13')
for conn in g:
    print(conn.host)
```

You can have look at the (updated!) docs [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.0/getting-started.html#run-commands-via-connections-and-run), and the (updated!) git repo [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric)

Comment: Simply by passing the connection object as an argument of your task, and looping through all the connections in the Group. Example here : https://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/getting-started.html#bringing-it-all-together

Comment: I use it command line `fab task`, so I don't pass connection object myself.